# Когда может потребоваться кастомный Манифест?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

VS, если я не ошибаюсь, всегда снабжает сборки манифестом, где описываются метаданные.

Но так же в проект можно добавить собственный манифест сборки.

Для чего это может потребоваться и какой в этом профит? Его заполняют ручками в XML или какой-то утилитой?

Answer (score 3):

Из того, что я применял — можно потребовать, чтобы ваше приложение запускалось [всегда с администраторскими правами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/276994):

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Если вы добавляете манифест, он заменяет манифест по умолчанию. Его проще всего редактировать руками. В том манифесте, который мне вставила Visual Studio 2015, все нужные секции присутствуют в закомментированном виде. Например:

```xml
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

Так что править вручную — не проблема.

Comment: он служит, как дополнение к генерируемому манифесту или полностью заменяет его=> ручками все зависимости прописывать? Его ручками правят или есть утилиты?

Comment: @iluxa1810: А какие зависимости?

Comment: ,https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1w45z383(v=vs.110).aspx говорят, что должны перечисляться необходимые сборки.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вроде бы это лишь дополнительная информация. Я создал приложение с манифестом без зависимостей, и оно вроде без проблем запустилось.